# Append all hrefs in class with hash

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append the hrefs inside all .drawer-filter-btns>a anchor tags with the URL fragment on page-load. The URL fragment is determined by the link from the previous page (for example, site.com/foo#bar) which I intend to have generate the URLs on this page to link to the various colour types available for each product sub-set.

At the moment my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="drawer-filter-btns">
    <a href="_door_type_a_drawer_type_1">link</a>
    <a href="_door_type_b_drawer_type_1">link</a>
    <a href="_door_type_a_drawer_type_2">link</a>
    <a href="_door_type_b_drawer_type_2">link</a>
    <a href="_door_type_a_drawer_type_3">link</a>
    <a href="_door_type_b_drawer_type_3">link</a>
    <a href="_door_type_a_drawer_type_4">link</a>
    <a href="_door_type_b_drawer_type_4">link</a>
</div>
```

It was easy enough figuring out the logic for just doing one:

```
var href = $(".drawer-filter-btns>a").attr('href');
var hash = location.hash.substr(1);
$(".drawer-filter-btns>a").attr('href', hash + href);
```

However the issue I have is that each button has a different href (before the JS is executed) but the code only takes into account the first and copies it over all of the hrefs inside .drawer-filter-btns>a, so my HTML becomes this (after code execution):

```
<div class="drawer-filter-btns">
    <a href="bar_door_type_a_drawer_type_1">link</a>
    <a href="bar_door_type_a_drawer_type_1">link</a>
    <a href="bar_door_type_a_drawer_type_1">link</a>
    <a href="bar_door_type_a_drawer_type_1">link</a>
    <a href="bar_door_type_a_drawer_type_1">link</a>
    <a href="bar_door_type_a_drawer_type_1">link</a>
    <a href="bar_door_type_a_drawer_type_1">link</a>
    <a href="bar_door_type_a_drawer_type_1">link</a>
</div>
```

Despite being new to JQuery / Javascript, I attempted to get around this using what logic I had learned from PHP, though it didn't work as intended.

```
$('.drawer-filter-btns>a').attr('href').each(function(){
    var href = $(".drawer-filter-btns>a").attr('href');
    var hash = location.hash.substr(1);
    $(".drawer-filter-btns>a").attr('href', hash + href);
});
```

What I am trying to do get the href variable to update with each link so that it appends all of them correctly. There may be a way to do this without setting the original href as a variable but I'm currently unskilled with Javascript.

Ideally, my final output will look like this:

```
<div class="drawer-filter-btns">
    <a href="bar_door_type_a_drawer_type_1">link</a>
    <a href="bar_door_type_b_drawer_type_1">link</a>
    <a href="bar_door_type_a_drawer_type_2">link</a>
    <a href="bar_door_type_b_drawer_type_2">link</a>
    <a href="bar_door_type_a_drawer_type_3">link</a>
    <a href="bar_door_type_b_drawer_type_3">link</a>
    <a href="bar_door_type_a_drawer_type_4">link</a>
    <a href="bar_door_type_b_drawer_type_4">link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hvh9rxbt/

```
var hash = "bar";
$('.drawer-filter-btns>a').each(
    function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).attr('href', hash + href);
    }
);
```

You want to iterate over the anchors and then get each ones href and update it by prepending the hash. You were iterating over each href and then selecting every anchor each time.

`$('.drawer-filter-btns>a').each(` this line iterates over every anchor in drawer-filter-btns. This line `var href = $(this).attr('href');` references the current anchor in the iteration with this and gets its href. `$(this).attr('href', hash + href);` and this line once again references the current anchor in the iteration and updates its href with the new value we created by prepending the hash value to the href.

I just added the hash variable with a default value in order to demonstrate in the fiddle.

As noted in the comments by A. Wollf because attr works on collections its not necessary to iterate over each anchor since jQuery will do it for you.

```
$('.drawer-filter-btns>a').attr('href', function(_, href){
        return hash + href;
});
```

And the fiddle created by A. Wollf: http://jsfiddle.net/hvh9rxbt/1/

And for reference since I was actually not aware of the ability to pass a function to the attr method:

http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function

Cool stuff!

Comment: You don't need each loop here, `attr()` setter works on collection  http://jsfiddle.net/hvh9rxbt/1/  Anyway, +1 because you fixed with detail OP's code

Comment: Thank you @AtheistP3ace for explaining your code amendments as well as providing reference material and A. Wolff for your optimised version. It's good to know I wasn't too far off!